# Does ansible support prototyping tasks?

Tags: ansible

Does ansible support prototyping tasks in a similar way that puppet does?

Like, in puppet I can do something like this:

```
File {
  notify => Service['httpd'],
}

file { '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf':
  source => "puppet:///modules/httpd/httpd.conf",
}
```

...where every file declaration will have the notify property of the initial File block unless the subsequent declaration overrides it.

Is there a functional equivalent in ansible? I'm thinking something like this

```
---
- prototype: task prototype
  notify:
  - command: "apachectl graceful"
- name: install a configuration
  copy: src=/opt/ansible/httpd/conf/httpd.conf dest=/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
  """something puts my notify here without me having to write it"""
```

Obviously not very useful for one file declaration but exceedingly useful if you have 20 of them.

Answer (score 0):

No, Ansible has nothing like that.

Though it *might* be possible to implement it yourself by creating an [action plugin](http://ndemengel.github.io/2015/01/20/ansible-modules-and-action-plugins/#action-plugins) and a [callback plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#callbacks). The action plugin would be the `prototype` declaration. The callback plugin can fire after any Ansible action, e.g. when a task successfully completes.

The only thing I'm not sure about is, if you can trigger a remote action or even a *notify* from within the callback plugin handlers.

Comment: Hmm, I may try to implement it then. Thanks.